# Unable to receive data from multiple UDP devices

Tags: c++, udp, ethernet

I am using the [EIPScanner library](https://github.com/nimbuscontrols/EIPScanner) to talk to 2 TURCK I/O modules via EthernetIP. The library works fine with one module, but the moment I instantiate the driver for the second one, the first one times out.

I tried to modify the library by passing a port number to listen on, but it didn't seem to make a difference:

In ConnectionManager.cpp

```
IOConnection::WPtr
    ConnectionManager::forwardOpen(const SessionInfoIf::SPtr& si,   ConnectionParameters connectionParameters, int port, bool isLarge) {
....
....
....
if (o2tSockAddrInfo != additionalItems.end()) 
{
    Buffer sockAddrBuffer(o2tSockAddrInfo->getData());
    sockets::EndPoint endPoint("",0);
    sockAddrBuffer >> endPoint;

    endPoint.setPort(port) 

    if (endPoint.getHost() == "0.0.0.0") {
        ioConnection->_socket = std::make_unique<UDPSocket>(
                si->getRemoteEndPoint().getHost(), endPoint.getPort());
    } else {
        ioConnection->_socket = std::make_unique<UDPSocket>(endPoint);
    }
            
}
```

I tried adding a timeout to the recvfrom() function, but that also didn't make a difference.

In UDPSocket.cpp

```
UDPSocket::UDPSocket(EndPoint endPoint)
        : BaseSocket(EndPoint(std::move(endPoint))) {

    _sockedFd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (_sockedFd < 0) {
        throw std::system_error(BaseSocket::getLastError(), BaseSocket::getErrorCategory());
    }
    /*struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 0;
    tv.tv_usec = 1;
    setsockopt(_sockedFd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &tv, sizeof(tv));*/
    Logger(LogLevel::DEBUG) << "Opened UDP socket fd=" << _sockedFd;
}
```

Output:

```
[DEBUG] Opened TCP socket fd=7
[DEBUG] Connecting to 192.168.1.130:44818
[INFO] Registered session 103
[DEBUG] Opened TCP socket fd=8
[DEBUG] Connecting to 192.168.1.131:44818
[INFO] Registered session 103
2021-06-18 13:03:02,996 Process-1       
2021-06-18 13:03:02,997 Process-1           [INFO] Send request: service=0x54 epath=[classId=6 objectId=1]
[INFO] Open IO connection O2T_ID=1781321728 T2O_ID=915406849 SerialNumber 1
[DEBUG] Opened UDP socket fd=15
[INFO] Open UDP socket to send data to 192.168.1.130:2223
[DEBUG] Opened UDP socket fd=16
[INFO] Will look for id: 915406849 from endPoint: 192.168.1.130:2222

[DEBUG] Received data from connection T2O_ID=915406849(host: 192.168.1.130:2223)
[DEBUG] Received: seq=2 data=[0][0][0][0]
[DEBUG] Received data from connection T2O_ID=915406849(host: 192.168.1.130:2223)
[DEBUG] Received: seq=3 data=[0][0][0][0]
2021-06-18 13:03:03,112 Process-2       
2021-06-18 13:03:03,113 Process-2       
[INFO] Send request: service=0x54 epath=[classId=6 objectId=1]
[INFO] Open IO connection O2T_ID=1782571776 T2O_ID=1911881729 SerialNumber 1
[DEBUG] Received data from connection T2O_ID=1911881729(host: 192.168.1.130:2223)
[DEBUG] Received: seq=1 data=[0][0][4][0]
[DEBUG] Opened UDP socket fd=20
[INFO] Open UDP socket to send data to 192.168.1.131:2224
[DEBUG] Opened UDP socket fd=21
[INFO] Will look for id: 1911881729 from endPoint: 192.168.1.131:2222

[DEBUG] Received data from connection T2O_ID=915406849(host: 192.168.1.131:2224)
[DEBUG] Received: seq=4 data=[0][0][0][0]
[DEBUG] Received data from connection T2O_ID=1911881729(host: 192.168.1.131:2224)
[DEBUG] Received: seq=2 data=[0][0][4][0]
```

As you can see once the device on 192.168.1.131 starts streaming, the 1.130 device stops. And eventually it times out and shuts down.

Comment: Without code I can't say much but "_I tried to modify the library_" is a red flag.

Comment: How did you try to modify the library? Please show code, in [example] form, with actual input, actual output, and expected output.

Comment: Apologies. I wasn't sure how much of the code I had to paste. I edited my OP.